# if else commands just staying on the first logic gate

Tags: if-statement, arduino, arduino-uno

This code is to make a simple rgb led thermometer. The problem i am having is that i have three color tiers of temperature, and something in my syntax is making it so the it only looks at the first logic gate. The code is shown below.

```
// code by luke aka lazerfire15
const int temp= (A0);
int (red)=(2);
int (green)=(3);
int (blue)=(4);
int (tempread); //holds a value for the temp read

void setup() 
{
pinMode (red,OUTPUT); //set inputs and outputs
pinMode (green,OUTPUT);
pinMode (blue,OUTPUT);
pinMode (temp,INPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  tempread=(analogRead(temp)/(2.05)); // i used serial print here to test the temp sensor
  analogRead(temp);
  delay (100);
    if ((tempread) >= (50) && (tempread) < (74)) {
   pinMode(blue,HIGH);  
 } 
else if ((tempread) >= (74) && (tempread) < (76)) {
   pinMode(green,HIGH);
 }
 else if ((tempread) >= (76)) {
   pinMode(red,HIGH);
 }
 }
```

Comment: if anyone needs more details in order to answer please ask me i would love your advice.

Comment: if it is bigger then 50, it will never get to bigger then 74 or 76, because it will ALWAYS enter the first if.

Comment: i have adjusted the parameters and it still did not work thank you though i must update this to the most recent code

Comment: there is still a logic error.. 71,72,73,74... will always go in to first if. please check my answer

Comment: okay i tried it exactly as is and it just does nothing i am going to do some serial print tests

Comment: what do you mean by does nothing? are you sure the tempread variable is containing what do you expect it to contain?

Comment: yes it does the led does not turn on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if ((tempread) >= (50)) {
   pinMode(blue,HIGH);  
 } 
else if ((tempread) >= (74)) {
   pinMode(green,HIGH);
 }
 else if ((tempread) >= (76)) {
   pinMode(red,HIGH);
 }
```

a simple logic error. it will always enter the first if because other else-ifs will be never reached.

- assume 75 -> bigger then 50, first if - ignore others
- assume 77 -> bigger then 50, first if - ignore others

you should change your logic as this

```
 if ((tempread) >= (50) && (tempread) < (74)) {
   pinMode(blue,HIGH);  
 } 
else if ((tempread) >= (74) && (tempread) < (76)) {
   pinMode(green,HIGH);
 }
 else if ((tempread) >= (76)) {
   pinMode(red,HIGH);
 }
```